# How do I append to a tuple?

Tags: rust, tuples

I have something which I know is a tuple. How do I generically append a single value to the tuple?

```rust
let some_tuple: (i32, &str, bool) = (1, "Hello", true);

let with_world: (i32, &str, bool, &str) = some_tuple.append("World");
```

---

As a possible use-case, consider a parser combinator which takes a variadic number of parsers and runs each in sequence, producing a tuple of their attributes:

```rust
// Emulate variadic parameters:
macro_rules! seq {
    ($($parsers:expr),*) => {
        move |input: &[u8]| {
            let result = ();
            let remaining = input;
            $(
                let (remaining, parser_result) = $parsers(remaining);
                let result = result.append(parser_result);
            )*
            result
        }
    }
}
```

With tuple appending, `seq!(a, b, c, d)` can yield `(A, B, C, D)`, rather than the ugly `(((A, B), C), D)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this, but we can implement it ourselves with a helper trait and a macro to implement that trait for tuples up to N arguments:

```rust
trait TupleAppend<T> {
    type ResultType;

    fn append(self, t: T) -> Self::ResultType;
}

impl<T> TupleAppend<T> for () {
    type ResultType = (T,);

    fn append(self, t: T) -> Self::ResultType {
        (t,)
    }
}

macro_rules! impl_tuple_append {
    ( () ) => {};
    ( ( $t0:ident $(, $types:ident)* ) ) => {
        impl<$t0, $($types,)* T> TupleAppend<T> for ($t0, $($types,)*) {
            // Trailing comma, just to be extra sure we are dealing
            // with a tuple and not a parenthesized type/expr.
            type ResultType = ($t0, $($types,)* T,);

            fn append(self, t: T) -> Self::ResultType {
                // Reuse the type identifiers to destructure ourselves:
                let ($t0, $($types,)*) = self;
                // Create a new tuple with the original elements, plus the new one:
                ($t0, $($types,)* t,)
            }
        }

        // Recurse for one smaller size:
        impl_tuple_append! { ($($types),*) }
    };
}

impl_tuple_append! {
    // Supports tuples up to size 10:
    (_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a906cc0c7ac56fe47e274410a22a337e)

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to a tuple, consider using an [`HList`](https://docs.rs/frunk/0.3.0/frunk/macro.hlist.html):

```
use frunk::hlist; // 0.3.0

fn main() {
    let some_values = hlist![1, "Hello", true];

    let with_world = some_values.prepend("World");

    println!("{:?}", with_world);
}
```